# Check boxes values pass with ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

i have a form with checkboxes.I am using $.ajax() to send values at php side.

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="order[]" value="cake"> cake
    <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="order[]" value="cupcake">cupcakes
    <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="order[]" value="cakepops">cakepops
    <input type="checkbox" id="4" name="order[]" value="whoopee pies">whoopee pies
    <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="order[]" value="cookies">cookies
```

the code i am using to send data at server is.

```
               var m_data = new FormData();
                m_data.append( 'user_name', $('input[name=name]').val());
                m_data.append( 'user_email', $('input[name=email]').val());
                m_data.append( 'user_order', $('input[name="order"]:checked').val());
 $.ajax({
                    url: 'get_mail.php',
                    data: m_data,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType:'json',
                    success: function(response){
                        //load json data from server and output message
                        if(response.type == 'error'){ 
                            output = '<div class="error">'+response.text+'</div>';
                        }else{
                            output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';
                        }
                        $("#contact_form #contact_results").hide().html(output).slideDown();
                    }
                });
```

I am stuck here can any body please help me..

Comment: Can you please elaborate where are you stuck, you are not able to get checkboxes value or you are not able to send it across via ajax?
What params do u get after the form submission?

Comment: i am not able to get check boxes value as i want them to receive via email using php.